# Disable all default HTTP error response content in Tomcat

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, httpresponse

By default, Tomcat sends some HTML content back to the client if it encounters something like an HTTP 404. I know that via `web.xml` an `<error-page>` [can be configured](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q6) to customize this content.

However, I'd just like for Tomcat to **not send anything** in terms of response content (I'd still like the status code, of course). Is there any way to easily configure this?

I'm trying to avoid A) explicitly sending empty content on the response stream from my Servlet, and B) configuring custom error pages for a whole bunch of HTTP error statuses in my `web.xml`.

For some background, I'm developing an HTTP API and am controlling my own response content. So for an HTTP 500, for example, I'm populating some XML content on the response containing error information. For situations like an HTTP 404, the HTTP response status is sufficient for clients, and the content tomcat is sending is unnecessary. If there's a different approach, I'm open to hearing it.

**Edit:**
After continued investigation, I still can't find much in the way of a solution. If someone can definitively say this is not possible, or provide a resource with evidence that it will not work, I'll accept that as an answer and try and work around it.

Comment: I'm not overloading the meaning of the codes, I'm using them as they're intended. This is for a REST API - as an example, if someone performs a GET on a certain resource in my API, and I don't find it, I'm setting the response status to 404. If I have some sort of strange error, I set a status of 500 and provide some error content in the response. But I want exclusive control over this content - I don't want Tomcat returning HTML or anything else. If content is to be returned, I want my Servlet to be the one doing it.

Comment: I just also found that Servlet 3 seems to allow for a one-catches-all <error-page>: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-customer-servlet-container-error-page

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you do not want tomcat to show an error page, do not use sendError(...). Instead, use setStatus(...).

e.g. if you want to give a 405 response, then you do

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);      
response.getWriter().println("The method " + request.getMethod() + 
   " is not supported by this service.");
```

Also, remember not to throw any Exceptions from your servlet. Instead, catch the Exception and, again, set the statusCode yourself.

i.e.

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  try {

    // servlet code here, e.g. super.service(request, response);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    // log the error with a timestamp, show the timestamp to the user
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log("Exception " + now, e);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    response.getWriter().println("Guru meditation: " + now);
  }
}
```

Of course, if you do not want any content, just don't write anything to the writer, and just set the status.

Comment: Using `print()` instead of `println()` which causes additional new line char. This especially useful if you are sending the empty string, with `Content-Length: 0`

Comment: I think the real reason why this works is because you've written to the output stream. I believe that if you simply set the status and do not write anything to the response, Tomcat will send the default error response for 405.

Comment: Simply setting the status code does not appear to be sufficient to suppress the standard error page (at least, not based on my own experience).

Comment: I had to call `flush()` on the writer to ensure my content was not overridden by Tomcat.

Comment: Also, this only works for an empty response, at least with 500 response code.

Comment: catching exceptions doesnt seem to work when `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown. error still shows up

Answer (score 46):

Although this doesn't respond exactly to the "not send anything" statement on the question, and on the wave of [Clive Evans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166149/1504300), I found out that, in tomcat, you can make those overly verbose texts go away from error pages without creating a custom ErrorReportValve.

You can accomplish this by customizing ErrorReportValve through the 2 params "showReport" and "showServerInfo" in your "server.xml":

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false" />
```

[Link to official documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve).

Worked for me on tomcat 7.0.55, didn't work for me on tomcat 7.0.47 (because of something reported on the following link, I think - http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg113856.html)

Comment: Working with Tomcat 8. Excellent solution!

Comment: The Tomcat docs say the <Valve /> element can go within the <Engine />, <Host /> or <Context /> elements in server.xml. For me putting the valve within the <Engine /> element didn't work but putting it inside individual <Host /> elements did.

The docs also say Tomcat routes any non matching host names to the <Host /> element that is set in the defaultHost attribute of the <Engine /> element. To ensure that URLs to locations outside of your hosts/contexts are not shown the error messages compiled into Tomcat you need to make sure this <Valve /> is added your default <Host />.

Answer (score 13):

The quick, slightly dirty, but easy way of stopping Tomcat from sending any error body is to call setErrorReportValveClass against the tomcat host, with a custom error report valve which overrides report to do nothing. ie:

```
public class SecureErrorReportValve extends ErrorReportValve {

@Override
protected void report(Request request,Response response,Throwable throwable) {
}

}
```

and set it with:

```
  ((StandardHost) tomcat.getHost()).setErrorReportValveClass(yourErrorValveClassName);
```

If you want to send your message, and just think Tomcat shouldn't mess with it, you want something along the lines of:

```
@Override
protected void report(final Request request, final Response response, final Throwable throwable) {
    String message = response.getMessage();
    if (message != null) {
        try {
            response.getWriter().print(message);
            response.finishResponse();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great! I like having a single place to control this rather than having to wrap every single response. More aspect-oriented.

Comment: Feel free to point to the part of the spec that says you shouldn't take the Tomcat ErrorReportValve which rewrites your message into a message containing a whole load of information you probably don't want to share with the outside world, and instead, write just your message. I'm intrigued ...

Comment: on another note, you can write your own ErrorValve and configure it in the server.xml's <Host> element:  

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"  
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" 
            errorReportValveClass="security.MyErrorValveImpl">  
  
see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html

Comment: Well, more than a "quick, slightly dirt" answer, looks like the answer that really meets the needs.

Comment: And now you application is tomcat dependant.

Comment: If you weren't using Tomcat, you wouldn't be suffering from Tomcat leaking your information ...

Comment: I needed to add `try {
            response.finishResponse();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }` to the empty `report()` method to prevent it from producing any output.

Answer (score 11):

Although it's Servlet spec compliant, for security reasons I don't want tomcat or any other Servlet container to send error details. I struggled with this as well a bit. After searching and trying, the solution can be summed up as:

1. as others mentioned, don't use `sendError()`, use `setStatus()` instead ([in Jersey framework you can choose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600434/505893))
2. frameworks like e.g. Spring Security use `sendError()` though...
3. write a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that
   a. redirects calls to `sendError()` to `setStatus()`
   b. flushes the response at the end to prevent the container from further modifying the response

[A little example servlet filter doing this can be found here](https://gist.github.com/4545911).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that frameworks have predefined behaviour and providing an example filter, which — as I'm using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) — made me discover a [a specific Jersey property](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.5/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR)

Comment: Above link posted by @watery is dead as of 2019, correct link now is https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR

Comment: Link is dead again, better look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600434/505893) ;)

Answer (score 10):

As [Heikki said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1451037), setting the status instead of `sendError()` causes Tomcat not to touch the response entity/body/payload.

If you only want to send the response headers without any entity, like in my case,

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
response.setContentLength(0);
```

does the trick. With `Content-Length: 0`, the `print()` will have no effect even if used, like:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
response.setContentLength(0);
response.getWriter().print("this string will be ignored due to the above line");
```

the client receives something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 28 Sep 2011 08:59:49 GMT
```

If you want to send some error message, use the `setContentLength()` with message length (other than zero) or you can leave it to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Though this question is a bit old, I ran into this problem too. First of all, Tomcat's behavior is absolutely correct. This is per Servlet Spec. One should not alter Tomcat's behavior against the spec. As Heikki Vesalainen and mrCoder mentioned, use `setStatus` and `setStatus` only.

To whom it may concern, I have raised a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54198) with Tomcat to improve the docs of `sendError`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the behavior being "absolutely correct"? Which behavior, specifically? A link or excerpt from the Servlet specification may help. I couldn't find anything in the 3.0 specification that addressed requirements on the actual content of a response, particularly for error responses. As far as [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) goes, there aren't any requirements on the entity content for any error statuses.

Comment: Yes, of course. This is not bound to the RFC but to the Servlet spec itself. Check Servlet spec 3.0, chapters 10.9.2 and 10.9.3, Oracle's Servlet API JavaDocs for both [`sendError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29) methods and my question to the [Tomcat Users Mailinglist](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg102755.html).

Answer (score 2):

#### Configure `<error-page>` Elements in `web.xml`

Edit `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml`, add at the end the following `<error-page>`, save and restart tomcat

```
<web-app>

...
...
...

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/500.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/400.html</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

- It works great as I expect even though I didn't actually created a valid routes for those specified `location` values (e.g. `/400.html`)

---

before

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: You missed the point where the OP said he's _trying to avoid [..] configuring custom error pages for a whole bunch of HTTP error statuses in [his] web.xml_.

Comment: Agree. Yet its helpful for those who google their way for examples. This question have good SEO rating.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just configure the `<error-page>` element with an empty HTML page?

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I would like to avoid configuring error pages (even if they're empty) for a bunch of statuses. If it's my only option then I guess I'll have to - but I'm looking for alternatives.