# How to make response 404 without any HTML body for RESTful?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I just use following code to response a 404:Not found.

`return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();`

While the response always with following body. How can i remove them?

[image]

Holp anyone can help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: http://linux-sxs.org/internet_serving/c581.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable all default HTTP error response content in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794329/disable-all-default-http-error-response-content-in-tomcat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAX-RS — How to return JSON and HTTP status code together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687271/jax-rs-how-to-return-json-and-http-status-code-together)