# Spring Boot + Tomcat Error Handling

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, error-handling, tomcat7

We have a web application built using spring boot and we are using spring security to manage authentication. Authentication is right now happening using basic mode.

We are using [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) to handle authentication. When we are running the application directly from STS using the embedded tomcat, when the user is not [enabled](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html#isEnabled()), we receive the following error with status code 401.

```
{"timestamp":1485512173312,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"User is disabled","path":"/trex/user"}
```

But, when I package the application into a war and deploy it to Tomcat we no longer receive the json error. Instead, we receive a html error similar to the following.

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.75 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - User is disabled</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>User is disabled</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.75</h3></body></html>
```

Is it possible to stop handling the standard error codes and let the json data pass back as it is?

**Edited:**
Spring security config

```
/**
 * Security configuration. Defines configuration methods and security
 * constraints. Autowired bean definitions can be found in {@link AuthAppConfig}
 * 

 *
 */
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    /*userDetailsService
     * @Autowired TRexUserDetailsService customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    TRexUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonProperties amazonProperties;

    /**
     * Configuration related to authentication and authorization
     * 
     * @param http
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        LogoutHandler myLogoutHandler = new MyLogoutSuccessHandler();

        logger.info("Configuring the security of the application");

        http

                // Basic Authentication
                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                // Allowing index.html, login.html and / and
                // resetforgotpassword.html and all forgot user mappings since
                // we are using 2 way handshake for this purpose
                .antMatchers("/activate/user","/activate/token/**"
                        ,"/validate","/validateEmail","/user/resetpassword/**","/user/forgotpassword"
                        ,"/admin/masters/*.js","/admin/modeller/*.js", "/login.html", "/index.html","/activateuser.html","/savepassword.html","/forgotpassword.html","/","/lib/**"
                        ,"/directives/paginated-control.js"
                        , "/expense/js/summary.js"
                        ,"/travel/js/directive/uploadDirecetive.js"
                        ,"/travel/js/travelData.js"
                        ,"/travel/js/summary.js"
                        ,"/directives/paginated-control.js"
                        ,"/loginform.html"
                        ,"/infoDirective.html"
                        )
                .permitAll()
                // Admin ADMIN,
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                // Allow SA
                .antMatchers("/SA/**").access("hasRole('SUPER')")
                //Allow REPORTS
                .antMatchers("/reports/**").access("hasRole('REPORT')")
                // All other requests are to be authenticated.
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

                // Filter to prevent CSRF attacks.
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).csrf()
                // Used to check which requests are to be checked for csrf
                // protection
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CsrfRequestMatcher())
                // Add the renamed CSRF token header repository
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                // Configuration for /logout
                .logout()
                // Logout requires form submit. Bypassing the same.
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/#/login")
                .addLogoutHandler(myLogoutHandler)
                //Session management to store session registry
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(100)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
                .expiredUrl("/#/login")
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

    }

    /**
     * Session Registry to store sessions
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    /**
     * Session event publisher.
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {        
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
    /**
     * This method specifies that the header name to be used is XSRF token
     * instead of the default CSRF cause Angular names the token as XSRF instead
     * of CSRF
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        logger.info("Configuring the CSRF token name as XSRF-TOKEN");
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }

    /**
     * Configuration for Custom Authentication
     * 
     * @param auth
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder)
            throws Exception {
        logger.info("Configuring the authentication to custom User Details Service");

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        logger.info("Configuring the authentication to custom User Details Service");
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() throws Exception {
        BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entryPoint.setRealmName("Spring");

        return entryPoint;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to fix this within your `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1451037/1084004) on how to avoid Tomcat's default error pages.

Assuming your custom EntryPoint is an extension of `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` (as the bean would suggest), see here:
[org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.java/#59](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.java/#59)

You'll need to replace:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
```

with:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```